# Filter data in Firebase - update method

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update an array in firebase-firestore to remove user updates. But of course I don't want to delete all updates, just some with the same id.

Firebase structure: collection('users').doc(uid).collection('updates).doc(uid) -> field('newJobRequests')[{String belongingJob, String requestedBy}]

If the structure is not understandable I can post a screenshot from Firebase. [Screenshot(firebase-structure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSjxp.jpg)

The marked Id is the one I want to filter & delete all objects in the Array (newJobRequests) with this id.

Heres my code to update the data:

```
await _firebaseFirestore
    .collection('users')
    .doc(uidCurrentUser)
    .collection('updates')
    .doc(uidCurrentUser)
    .update({
  'newJobRequests': ([//here changed-data])
});
```

Is it possible to filter for the String belongingJob(id) in firebase and delete just the elements with the same id in the Array 'newJobRequests'?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no, it isn't.  Firebase "Array" are not really arrays - they are more like ordered lists of elements.  You *can* remove array elements - but they have to be matched *exactly* - *all* of the element, not just part. In your case, you would have to match `{String belongingJob, String requestedBy}` to use fieldValue arrayRemove (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-arrayremove)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As ist is not possible to filter the array, do you know a way to handle user-updates on firebase the best way? For example I want to show the user if he had a new application on a document and, if he accepts one, all other notifications should be deleted. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that that is both (a) another question and (b) FAR FAR too vague to be a useful answer for others.

Comment: BUT - all of that said - Firestore arrays are NOT very useful.  On the other hand, collections & documents are essentially free, and *are* searchable.